# How to stop BackgroundWorker from queuing?

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
{
    BackgroundWorker t = new BackgroundWorker();

    t.DoWork += SOME DB METHOD THAT TAKES 5 SECONDS
    t.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

When I profile this in SQL I notice that the `BackgroundWorker` appears to be queuing the threads in such a way that only 4 or 5 active connections are open at the same time vs. all 500 connections opening at once. I get no timeouts or blocking from my DB. How can I prevent this queuing and hit the database with all 500 concurrent threads at once?

Comment: thats a very bad idea.

Comment: Simply creating 500 threads doesn't mean you are going to have 500 threads running. If anything you will actually slow down your application by making the OS work harder checking all of your threads!

Comment: I should add, I am doing this to load test a method that will be on a high volume website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` uses the ThreadPool. You can adjust the ThreadPool with `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` and `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`. If it will be actually possible to establish that many connections to your database server may be another question (and cause other problems).

However, it's not recommendable to start 500 `BackgroundWorker` instances! A better solution could be provided by the "Task Parallel Library" with the Task class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am load testing a method used in a high volume website, so I actually WANT to cause problems if there are any. Perhaps I should have just asked the best way to load test a method.

Comment: @Coltech To properly load test you can't just have one machine mock a ton of clients; you need a lot of client machines.  Your problem is that your client machine is hitting it's limits well before the server it hitting *its* limits.  You need it to be the other way around to load test.

Comment: What JeffRSon is saying (I think) is that even if you really really want to do this, don't use a BackgroundWorker.

Instead, bump ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(500) ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(500) and run the code in a Parallel.For loop.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => { SOME DB METHOD THAT TAKES 5 SECONDS },
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
);
```

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx):

> **LongRunning** - Specifies that a task will be a long-running,
>   coarse-grained operation involving fewer, larger components than
>   fine-grained systems. It provides a hint to the TaskScheduler that
>   oversubscription may be warranted. Oversubscription lets you create
>   more threads than the available number of hardware threads.

---

Or, you could completely bypass the thread pool and use the [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) class directly:

```
var t = new Thread(() => { SOME DB METHOD THAT TAKES 5 SECONDS });
t.Start();
```

"Raw" threads will be harder to work with than tasks, though...

Answer (score 0):

You don't, since your computer can't possibly run 500 threads at once. Most probably, you're having 8 to 16 logical threads, and 4 or 5 is what's left available when you run your code. Seems 100% legit.

Comment: I am actually attempting to load test a method that will run on a high volume website. So it is completely possible that a LOT of threads will be hitting it at once. Is there a better option for me to load test this?